# Help me identify what set this bag of mostly white tiles and panels belongs to

Tags: set-identification

[image]

Can anyone tell me what set this bag belongs to?  It could be 2011 but not sure.

Comment: Have you tried to check the set inventory of the 10214 Tower Bridge? It seems that you have several bags from that set.

Answer (score 3):

As Aziraphale hinted at in a comment, this is a bag from [Tower Bridge (10214)](https://brickset.com/sets/10214-1/Tower-Bridge).

[image: Tower Bridge set photo]

You can see this bag clearly in [unboxing videos](https://youtu.be/TtyEHdgbmg4?t=77).